# Error when calling method in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Im getting an error that this.filterEvents is not define when calling a method from an onChange event in my class ? Cant quite figure out why?

I've tried calling it with Datepicker.filterEvents or this.constructor.filterEvents and this.filterEvents() -  without any luck :( - So hoping someone can point me in the right direction on where the error is?

Code here:

```
const daterangeConfig = {
  mode: "range",
  minDate: "today",
  dateFormat: "j M",
  weekNumbers: true,
  locale: 'da',
  onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr) { //instance also param
    //update filter label with selected dates
    let filterBtn = document.querySelectorAll('[data-filterTrigger]');
    let filterBtnIndex = 1;
    let filterLabelTargetSpan = filterBtn[filterBtnIndex].nextElementSibling.querySelector('.btn--filter__labelb');
    filterLabelTargetSpan.innerText = dateStr;
    Datepicker.filterEvents(selectedDates);
  }
};

class Datepicker {
  constructor(container) {
    // Run initializing code once the DOM is ready.
    onReady(() => this.init(container));
    // You can put other initializer-code here if it isn't dependent on the DOM in any way.
    this.picker = new Flatpickr(this.dom.container, daterangeConfig);
  }

  init(container) {
    this.dom = {
      container
    };
  }

  filterEvents(dates) {
    console.log("filter events now");
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use it without instantiating  the class that need to have static in front of the method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Static_methods

Comment: Please show us the code of `Flatpickr` and how it uses `daterangeConfig`

Comment: `filterEvents` is a method of the *instance*, not of the `Datepicker` class. Please also show us how/where (and how often) you construct a `new Datepicker`.

Comment: If `filterEvents` does not need to use `this` (as in `this.dom` or `this.picker`), just make it a `static` method.

Comment: Setting up an onReady handler inside an object constructor sounds extremely wrong. The onReady handler should instantiate your object instead.

Answer (score 0):

If `filterEvents()` is intended as a static method, meaning its logic is relevant to the `DatePicker` class but independent of any instance, then you can make it a static method as follows

```
class DatePicker {
  static filterEvents(dates) {
    ...
  }
}
```

and refer to it as `DatePicker.filterEvents`.

In your code, you define `filterEvents()` as an instance method rather than a static method, which makes it accessible to instances of `DatePicker` but not available as a method of the `DatePicker` class. If you do intend to perform logic in `filterEvents()` which depends on a specific instance, then `filterEvents()` should be declared as you have done without the use of the `static` keyword and be referenced as `this.filterEvents`. It's important to understand that the `this` must refer to the relevant `DatePicker` instance.

See also the [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method which may be useful depending on the desired behavior and code structure.